# .= operator in perl

Tags: perl

Can someone explain me what is happening here? I am trying to read a Downloaded-XML file

```
while(<MY-FILE>) {
 chomp;
 $contents .= $_;#what is this doing?
```

}

thanks in advance

Comment: Specifically: https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Additive-Operators and https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Assignment-Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot (`.`) is the concatenation operator in Perl.

```
$string = $a_substring . $another_substring;
```

Sometimes you want to concatenate text to the same variable.

```
$string = $string . $some_extra_text;
```

Most binary operators in Perl have an "assignment" version which simplifies code like this. So instead of:

```
$total = $total + $line_value;
```

You can just write:

```
$total += $line_value;
```

Syntax like this can be found in pretty much any C-style programming language.

In Perl, the concatenation operator has an assignment version. So instead of:

```
$string = $string . $some_extra_text;
```

You can just write:

```
$string .= $some_extra_text;
```

So, reversing that logic, your code:

```
$contents .= $_;
```

Is just a shortcut for:

```
$contents = $contents . $_;
```

Comment: you beautifully answered my question. Thanks a lot.